# Noob question SSH - Ethernet issues on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: networking, ssh, internet, ethernet

I have spent some time troubleshooting the issues I mentioned in a previous message and this is what I have come up with. I am only having problem with ethernet, wireless is working with no issues. I decided to change my static IP addresses back to dhcpv4 again (there initial setting) but this did not solve the problem. The only thing it did was close the ports that were open previously when I had a static ip such as port 22. The troubleshooting done below was with dhcpv4 not static ips.

The physical Ethernet connection (LAN3) to my router is working:

[image]

The Ethernet cables are connected to a switch like this:

[image]

For some reason whichever motherboard is the first to login gets a nice green LED light:

[image]

When another motherboard boots up but hasn’t login yet, the Ethernet cable looks like this:

[image]

when I ping its IP address I get this message:

> …destination host unreachable”

When I attempt to ssh in I get:

> …port22: no route to host

When I did this

```
sudo lsof -I -P -n | grep LISTEN
```

command on the motherboard with the green Ethernet light:

systemd-r 721 was the only port that was open.

Additionally, I did a `nmap` on the that same motherboard$s IP address I got:

> All 1000  scanned ports on… are closed

To add more confusion I was able to connect to the internet no problem so the https port was obviously open!

I also checked the firewall on each motherboard connected to Ethernet and I got the same result for all of them:

[image]

The router only recognises the IP addresses with dhcp that are connected to WiFi. As I stated above once I login the ethernet seemed to work but only machines I have logged into. If I boot the motherboards with ethernet plugged in but not logged in, those motherboards are not connected to the network and cannot be sshed into.

The mining boss is an ssh client. It is not a ssh server. The remaining motherboards in the ethernet network are ssh servers. All ethernet motherboards are running ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Would appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks.

Comment: "I have spent some time troubleshooting the issues I mentioned in a previous message and this is what I have come up with." You can't really start a question with this. It's very unclear what the problem is, and what you tried to solve it. Try restructuring your question from the beginning, being very clear: What is your setup, what is the problem and what did you try?

Comment: Smells like a possible IP address collision. Use `ip addr` on each system to check the assigned IP address and MAC address. Look for collisions (duplicates). Check your DHCP server to ensure it's really working. Check your DHCP server settings to ensure the pool of addresses is large enough.